# Unique Identifier for a Windows Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

What is the name for the unique Identifier for a Windows Phone App?

Comment: What is your question exactly?
Do you want to know how to identify an app/device? Maybe have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the GUID that identifies the app, as described by MSDN is App Id.

[CurrentApp.AppId - appId property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.appid?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

The data type of appID is [GUID (Globally Unique IDentifier)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.guid?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) which is a structure defined in the `system` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The Unique Identifier of your Application is the "GUID" [or product ID] (for [Globally Unique IDentifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier))

You can find it in your WPAppManifest.xml inside your project folder.